# Screenshot snipping tool using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a screenshot snipping tool for my browser using JS. I found html2canvas but i want the user to be able to capture a resizable screenshot so how do i make the gui which makes a box which user can resize and we capture everything inside the box for the screenshot.

If html2canvas is the way then how do i get the elements inside the box to capture on the canvas?

I saw some electron/react implementations but is it possible without those frameworks?

Comment: Would this be the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126334/13700000?